# Changing Time Format 09:30:00 to 9.30am

Tags: php

I have times stored in the database in this format

```
09:30:00
```

And of course I can display them on the page in that format. But how do I display it in the following format?..

```
9.30am
```

I have looked for a solution but can't find anything that does just this.

Comment: You can either format date in you mysql select ... or in php. I let you do a bit of research and come back if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the date() function to convert time formats.

```
$time = date("g:ia", strtotime("09:30:00"));
```

Broken down time formatting:

- g - Hours in 12 hour format
- : - Colon character
- i - Minutes with leading zeros
- a - am or pm

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$timeval = date("g:i a", strtotime("09:30:00"));
```